# preg_match : match pattern, ignore embeded patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is too advanced for me. Looking to match either side of (#MAIN_NAME)

```
[ ... [...(#INNERLEFT)...] ... (#MAIN_NAME) ... [...(#INNERRIGHT)...] ... ]

First preg_match :   ... [...(#INNERLEFT)...] ... 
Second preg_match :  ... [...(#INNERRIGHT)...] ...
```

More simply:

```
[------match1--------(#NAME)--------match2----------]
```

Comment: It would seem you just need `explode()`, at least based on your example. You should probably add an example that illustrates the condtions you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split your string on the nominated substring/delimiter and remove the leading and trailing square brackets, use `explode()` and `substr()` like this:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/058108e9d769e03bb0f9ea24a74bc1e6cb900cc0))

```
$string='[------match1--------(#NAME)--------match2----------]';    
$result=explode('(#NAME)',substr($string,1,-1));
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '------match1--------',
  1 => '--------match2----------',
)
```